# Why is the support of a divisor on a compact Riemann Surface is finite?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I know that a closed and discrete subset of a compact is finite. But I am not sure that the support of a divisor is closed.
How can I assure that?

Comment: What definition of a divisor are you using? Some definitions say simply that a divisor is a linear combination of a finite set of points, or equivalently an element of the free abelian group generated by the points.

Comment: I am using this definition: a divisor on a Riemann surface is a formal sum of point of the Riemann surface where the coefficient of every point is not zero only for a discrete subset of X.

Comment: In that case, I would expect that the concept of a "formal sum" requires, implicitly, that the sum be finite. Infinite sums, if allowed, are usually expressed very, very explicitly.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure about that because the book I am following then define the degree of a divisor only for divisors on compact Riemann, and says that the finiteness we use in defining the degree is granted by the discreteness and the compactness.

Comment: @AlessandroPecile Are you sure the support is only defined to be discrete and not also closed? Because it is an easy exercise to prove that any closed discrete subset of a compact space is finite.

Comment: Yes, in the book it is defined like i wrote (Miranda, pag. 129). Maybe the definiton is given in this terms because meromorphic functions' zeroes and poles not always are a finite subset of the Riemann surface.

Comment: That passage in the book about "the discreteness and the compactness" might be a bit carelessly stated, although I cannot be sure without seeing the exact quote. But you would be completely safe in adding finiteness to the definition of a divisor on a compact Riemann surface.

Comment: The support of actual divisors associated to meromorphic functions (and other things) are closed; that's not hard to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Just to remove this question from unaswered and for future reference, since I had the same problem, I will expand a bit @Lee Mosher comment.

Forster defines a divisor on a (not necessarily compact) Riemann surface $X$ as a mapping $$D:X \to Z$$ such that for any compact subset $K\subset X$, $D(x)\ne 0$ only for finitely many points $x \in K$. This is easily seen to imply both that $\mathrm{supp }\, D$ is always discrete and finite in the case $X$ is compact.

This seems to a me a better definition than Miranda's. Probably Miranda uses another definition of "discrete", this is not the only passage of his book where this is evident.

Comment: Miranda seems using (discrete subset + compact space $\implies$ finite subset) in the whole book which is quite confusing. Thank you for pointing out an alternative and better definition.